# Is there a way to delete a row in a dataframe if two rows have one matching value and one non-matching value?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's an example of my data:

```
dat <- data.frame("date" = c("2020-07-21", "2020-07-22", "2020-07-23", "2020-07-24", "2020-07-24", "2020-07-24"), 
                  "name" = c("ramsay","walton", "franklin", "allen", NA, "wilson"), 
                  "group" = c("0","0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), 
                  "total" = c(112, 56, 215, 283, 12, 18))
```

Is there a way (preferably using dplyr) to delete the 5th row in this dataframe based on the fact that it has the same date as another row, but a different group (if the dates match and the groups don't match, I always want to keep group "0")?

So basically, if I row_bind() new data to this dataframe, I never want to have two different groups on the same day, and if there are two different groups on the same day, I always want to keep the values in group "0" and delete the values in other groups.

Comment: @akrun yep, the original data has multiple observations per date, that's fine as long as they are all group "0".

Comment: Can you please check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create logical vector of duplicate elements with `duplicated` and (`&`) the 'group' value as 1, negate (`!`) the expression in `filter` to remove those rows that are duplicated with group 1

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  filter(!((duplicated(date)|duplicated(date, fromLast = TRUE)) & group == "1"))
#        date     name group total
#1 2020-07-21   ramsay     0   112
#2 2020-07-22   walton     0    56
#3 2020-07-23 franklin     0   215
#4 2020-07-24    allen     0   283
#5 2020-07-24   wilson     0    18
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
subset(dat, !((duplicated(date)|duplicated(date, fromLast = TRUE)) & group == "1"))
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, we could group by 'date', `filter` by checking whether there are more than 1 group (`n_distinct(group) > 1`) and if the 'group' is 1, negate (`!`) to make the TRUE=> FALSE, and viceversa

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    filter(!(n_distinct(group) > 1 & group == 1))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   date [4]
#  date       name     group total
#  <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#1 2020-07-21 ramsay   0       112
#2 2020-07-22 walton   0        56
#3 2020-07-23 franklin 0       215
#4 2020-07-24 allen    0       283
#5 2020-07-24 wilson   0        18
```

Comment: So, this solution works according to the sample data, which is awesome. But in my original data, there are instances where there are duplicate dates across group 1, and I want to keep those since there aren't any group 0 values for those dates.

Comment: @Christian updated the post.  Haven't tested all the cases but I guess based on your logic, it should work

Comment: A small thing, but in this approach every date-grouping gets both tests `(n_distinct(group) >1 & group==1)` evaluated and filtered. Whereas an `if(){}else{}` statement will only evaluate the `group==1` and do filtering if the distinct test fails. This could affect performance in a large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

For each `date` we can select rows where number of rows is greater than 1 and `group = 0` OR number of rows is 1.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(date) %>% filter(n() > 1 & group == 0 | n() == 1)

#  date       name     group total
#  <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#1 2020-07-21 ramsay   0       112
#2 2020-07-22 walton   0        56
#3 2020-07-23 franklin 0       215
#4 2020-07-24 allen    0       283
#5 2020-07-24 wilson   0        18
```

Answer (score 1):

I made your example dataset better by adding some group==1 rows that you'd actually want to keep.

```
dat <- data.frame("date" = c("2020-07-21", "2020-07-22", "2020-07-23", "2020-07-24", "2020-07-24", "2020-07-24","2020-07-25","2020-07-25"), 
                  "name" = c("ramsay","walton", "franklin", "allen", NA, "wilson","bob","john"), 
                  "group" = c("0","0", "0", "0", "1", "0","1","1"), 
                  "total" = c(112, 56, 215, 283, 12, 18,27,12))
```

This solution just tests whether there are more than one unique values of group within sets of rows that have the same date.

If there's only one unique value of group, it returns that set of rows back (ie does nothing).  If there is more than one unique value of group, it returns that set of rows subsetted to where group==0.

If you're not familiar with data.table, you can think of a data.table call with a `by` variable specified as a loop that iterates through each value of the `by` variable (in this case, date).  `.SD` refers to the subset of `dat` within each iteration of the loop. So `.SD` always refers to the subset of rows that have the same `by` variable (e.g. in this example `.SD` refers to the rows that have the same date). The result of each iteration are then rbinded together into one data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat <- dat[, if(uniqueN(group)==1){.SD}else{.SD[group==0, ]}, by=c("date")]
```